# MXRecord error when running diagnostics on hMailServer

Tags: hmail-server

I have downloaded and installed `hmailserver`. I want to run it on my local machine and want to send email using a local web application which is also running on my local machine. My web application couldn't send email (got error - `couldn't connect to mydomain:25`) and thus I thought to first run `hmailserver`'s diagnostic tool to test things.

But when I run diagnostics on it, I see the error:

`Test: Collect server details`
`hMailServer version: hMailServer 5.6.7-B2425`
`Database type: MSSQL Compact`

`Test: Test IPv6`
`IPv6 support is available in operating system.`

`Test: Test outbound port`
`SMTP relayer not in use. Attempting mail.hmailserver.com:25...`
`Trying to connect to host mail.hmailserver.com...`
`Trying to connect to TCP/IP address 5.189.183.138 on port 25.`
`Received: 220 mail.hmailserver.com ESMTP.`
`Connected successfully.`

`Test: Test backup directory`
`ERROR: Backup directory has not been specified.`

`Test: Test MX records`
`Trying to resolve MX records for mydomain.com...`
`ERROR: MX records for domain mydomain.com could not be resolved`

`Test: Test local connect`
`Connecting to TCP/IP address in MX records for local domain domain mydomain.com...`
`ERROR: MX records for local domain mydomain.com could not be resolved`

`Test: Test message file locations`
`Relative message paths are stored in the database for all messages.`

`Test: Test IP range configuration`
`No problems were found in the IP range configuration.`

To be honest, I don't know what `MX Record` is and how to set it up. Things I have done so far are:

1. Installed hmailserver (obviously!)
2. Added a domain (mydomain.com)
3. Added an account in mydomain.com (signup@mydomain.com)
4. In settings->Protocols ->SMTP, I added localhost in Delivery of email ->Localhostname section
5. In `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file, I added entry `127.0.0.1 mydomain.com #for play application`
6. When I run `netstat -a`, I see that `hmailserver` is listening on `port 25` (I tested it using `net stop hmailserver` and `net start hmailserver`)
   `Proto Local Address Foreign Address State`
   `TCP 0.0.0.0:25 DESKTOP-6PLQOLJ:0 LISTENING[/list]`

Have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This Error Message is shown if your Windows Operating system `DNS-Resolver` Service points to an `DNS-Server` which doesn't know anything or cannot forward the Query to the `DNS-Server` in charge for the specified Domain and its MX-Record.

In short terms: Without having your DNS-Domain correctly configured, `hMailServer` (or any other `SMTP-Server`) can't work.

Comment: How would you go about configuring the MX record?